# How to get AssemblyInformationalVersion from file in Python 3

Tags: python, assemblyinfo, nuget-spec

I am getting an `Invalid AssemblyInformationalVersion` error when trying to run 
`nuget spec -Force -a 'path/to/dll.dll'` in a python script. Is it possible to manipulate this value from within python?